# How do Reactjs, Nextjs, Nestjs, GraphQL, PostgreSQL, RabbitMQ, and Kafka all work together?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, apache-kafka, rabbitmq

I'm about to tackle a project with this stack:

- Frontend - ReactJS and NextJS
- Backend - NestJS and GraphQL
- PostgreSQL for Database
- RabbitMQ (message broker)
- Kafka (distributed event streaming)

Can someone help me understand how these all work together? I have a solid understanding of the frontend stuff, but as for the final four bullet points, I'm still learning. I've done a good bit of research on them but would appreciate a more experienced dev's explanation of the tech and perspective on this setup.

Comment: I think you're looking for terms "distributed systems" and "software architecture". Try googling, they are good starting points.

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't use both Rabbit and Kafka in the same architecture unless you're migrating between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- NextJS is a React Framework
- NestJS is a backend that can host a GraphQL API for (optional) usage from the frontend
- Your backend can utilize many clients for storing and transferring data, such as a database (Postgres) and messaging systems (Rabbit and/or Kafka)